# Computing the Group Ring $k[\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z]$ for a Field $k$ of Characteristic $0$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, ring-homomorphism, group-rings

Consider a field $k$ of characteristic $0$ and a positive integer $n.$ In the proof of Theorem 4.19 of *Polytopes, Rings, and K-Theory* by Bruns and Gubeladze, it is stated that we have an isomorphism $k[\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z] \cong k[x] / (x^n - 1),$ where $k[\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z]$ is the group ring corresponding to the cyclic group of integers modulo $n;$ however, I am having difficulty convincing myself of this. I believe that the $k$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi : k[x] \to k[\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z]$ induced by the assignment $x^m \mapsto \overline m$ is surjective, where we denote $\overline m = m \text{ (mod } n),$ so I would like to show that $\ker \varphi = (x^n - 1),$ but I have not been able to do this.

I would greatly appreciate any insight, comments, or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Well, what's the minimum polynomial of [1] in $k[\mathbb{Z}/n]$?

Comment: I believe that $\varphi(x^n - 1) = 0$ in $k[\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z],$ but how can I prove the reverse inclusion that $\ker \varphi \subseteq (x^n - 1)?$

Comment: You need to think about the minimal polynomial! The elements [1], [2],... are linearly independent

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a bit confused. Let me attempt to clarify: you are asking for the polynomial $p(t)$ in $k[\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z][t]$ of least degree such that $p(\overline 1) = \overline 0?$

Comment: Yes. My point is that if you have a $k$-algebra $\Lambda$ generated by a single element $x$ with min poly m then $\Lambda \cong k[X]/m(X)$. In the finite-dimensional case it's easy to see this because both sides have the same dimension and there's an obvious surjection.  In your case the min poly of [1] is $X^n-1$ because any smaller degree poly is a linear combination of [0],[1],...[n-1] and these are linearly independent.

Comment: I concur. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the first question. The kernel contains $x^n-1$. The polynomial  ring is PID so the kernel is generated by some polynomial $f(x)$. Then the remainder $r(x)$ of $f$ when divided by $x^n-1$ must belong to the kernel. That $r(x)$ has degree $<n$. Easy linear algebra then shows that $r$ is $0$. Hence the kernel is generated by $x^n-1$.

Comment: Essentially, this is what Matthew Towers is suggesting, correct? If we write $r(x) = a_{n - 1} x^{n - 1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0,$ then $0 = \varphi(r(x)) = a_{n - 1} \overline{n - 1} + \cdots + a_1 \overline 1 + a_0 \overline 0,$ but these are linearly independent, so we must have that $r(x) = 0.$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "easy linear algebra" shows that $r$ is $0.$ Could you possibly elaborate on that?

Comment: The argument is correct. As for "essentially the same" I do not know.